# How to build dynamic collection of objects with parameters stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am running a Rails 3.2 app with a MySQL DB and I want to build a model which is kind of a dynamic collection for example I will call it `Album`.

An Album should contain multiple instances of another model for example I call them `Item`s but I don't want to relate them only statically with a one-to-many join-table.

It should be possible also to define criteria like:

- `Album` contains `Item`s from start-date to end-date
- `Album` contains `Item`s where flag XY is "foo"
- ..

these criteria / parameters should be stored persistently in the database. `Item`s should not be linked once, new `Item`s should be attached to an album if they match the parameters

Number of parameters should be flexible e.g multiple time-ranges for an Album should be possible. So i think about an extra table which stores the relation between an Album and the matched time-ranges.

What would be be the best / most performant way to implement way this and make all Items within an `Album` accessible over a simple `album.items` call?

How/where should I store the parameters for the dynamic linking?

Comment: So you want to store an essentially arbitrary query in the database?

Comment: No not really. The criteria for the collection should not be completely arbitrary. I am thinking about 3 possible criteria like the mentioned time range. So not the query itself has to be stored only the parameters for the query e.g. the start and end date of the time-range.

Comment: But you're still storing a broken down query. And you have 3 criteria today but that will almost certainly change (and probably at 03:00 the day before a release). If you can specify your conditions in an array then you could serialize them using `serialize`.

Comment: Number of criteria should not really change that way. I would prefer if the parameters of the criteria like start and end date can be edit so a simple serialize of the query would not allow this i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could create an `ItemSet` class, since each `Album` can have multiple sets of criteria. `ItemSet` could have various subclasses using single table inheritance (or you could possibly achieve this kind of behavior another way; see [here](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html)), and you could define the `items` method in each subclass depending on which kind of `ItemSet` it was (based on date, flag set, etc.). `album.items` would be the union of the `items` in each of `album.item_sets`.

Comment: when i have a class ItemSet and Sublcasses for each kind of criteria how should the relation to the Album from the all the Subclasses of ItemSet look like?

Comment: @alex: if you're using single table inheritance, I think you could just put `belongs_to :album` in the `ItemSet` class, but I'm not positive. [This link](http://www.alexwestholm.com/tech/rails-single-table-inheritance-and-polymorphic-associations-some-simple-examples/) seems to indicate that that's what you do.

Comment: thanks a lot - I think you are pointing me in a good direction! I will come up with my final solution if my implementation is completed!